# Magento 1.7.0.2 and Paypal Advanced not working

Tags: paypal, magento-1.7

I've been trying to activate Paypal Payments Advanced in Magento 1.7.0.2 but it's simply not working. I believe the whole setup is correct, in the shopping cart and in the Paypal account, I have verified against the Paypal documentation as well as researched on the web.

I can go through the whole checkout and select credit card in the payment options, which displays the message "You will be required to enter your payment details after you place an order.", then when I click the Place Order button, it goes to the Shopping cart page without asking for the payment, and the cart is empty. The order then shows in the admin with the status pending payment.

I noticed on the console that before the redirect to the cart page, there is a 500 error with this url .../checkout/onepage/saveOrder/

I also seem 500 erros when calling other pages related to the Paypal Advanced like: .../index.php/paypal/payflowadvanced/cancelPayment or .../index.php/paypal/payflowadvanced/returnUrl

Any help would be appreciated, I already confirmed Curl is installed and working, SSL certificate is installed and working, the settings in the Paypal account like Enable Secure Token is Yes, all services under Service Summary say Live, so I have a feeling something is broken in Magento.

Have you seem this issue? Or were you able to install Paypal Advanced in any Magento 1.7.0.2?

Comment: Have you extended the Mage core at all or are you using any 3rd party extensions at checkout?

Answer (score 2):

Did some more searching on this topic and came across: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898392/magento-500-error-paypal-payments-advanced

Deleting my paypal.xml file from my custom theme directory solved the problem for me.  PayPay is now working correctly!

Comment: I am facing the Same problem and I also deleted the paypal.xml file from my custom theme directory, but still didn't work. Please someone help me out.